# Error 6046: Unable to generate function import return type of the store function

Tags: entity-framework, linq, user-defined-functions, sql-function

I have a scalar-valued function in my SQL database.

I receive this error when importing this function into Entity Framework model:

> Error 6046: Unable to generate function import return type of the store function 'GetContentByIdAndCul'.
> The store function will be ignored and the function import will not be generated. ..\EntityModels.edmx

My function T-SQL is:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [FRM].[GetContentByIdAndCul] 
    (@Id int,@Culture nvarchar(5))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @Result nvarchar(max)

    if @Id is not null
        set @Result='This Content not defined in this Language'
    
    select @Result=Value from CUL.Contents
    WHERE ID=@Id AND (CUL.Contents.Culture = LOWER(@Culture) 
          OR CUL.Contents.Culture = LOWER(SUBSTRING(@Culture,1,2))) 
    return @Result      
END
```

Answer (score 16):

**Preceding answers show the good way to solve the problem but none works in real life.**

Here's a tested solution with Entity Framework 6 that works for me. So it should works for you.

### Import your scalar valued function

Import your scalar valued function `[FRM].[GetContentByIdAndCul]` into your Entity Framework model. It automatically creates corresponding entry in the storage model of your `EntityModels.edmx` file:

```xml
<Function Name="GetContentByIdAndCul" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="FRM" ReturnType="nvarchar(max)">
    <Parameter Name="Id" Type="int" Mode="In" />
    <Parameter Name="Culture" Type="nvarchar(5)" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

### Add code to wrap call to your scalar valued function

Create new source file and add code to auto generated `DbContext` class (say her name is `MyEntities`) using Partial class mechanism (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

```cs
public partial class MyEntities
{
    [DbFunction("EntityModels.Store", "GetContentByIdAndCul")]
    public string GetContentByIdAndCul(int id, string culture)
    {
       var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

       var parameters = new List<ObjectParameter>();
       parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("Id", id));
       parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("Culture", culture));

       return objectContext.CreateQuery<string>("EntityModels.Store.GetContentByIdAndCul(@Id, @Culture)", parameters.ToArray())
            .Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

### Use your scalar valued function

Client code:

```cs
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    int id = 1;
    string culture = "fr-FR";
    string result = null;

    result = context.GetContentByIdAndCul(id, culture);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Until today, entity framework doesn't suport generating calls for scalar functions.
But, you can solve the problem writting a custom method like this inside your DbContext class:

```
public partial class YouDbContext
{
    [DbFunction("YouDbContext.Store", "YourScalarFunction")]
    public string YourScalarFunction(string parameter)
    {
        var lObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

        return lObjectContext.
            CreateQuery<string >(
                "YouDbContext.Store.YourScalarFunction", 
                new ObjectParameter("parameterName", parameter)).
            Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking).
            FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its 2019 EF 6.3 and its still doesn't get support. So i'm back to Linq to SQL

Answer (score 6):

Create a partial class for YOURMODEL.Context.cs: `public partial class YOUREntities : DbContext`

```
[DbFunction("YOURModel.Store", "YOURSCALARFUNCTION")]
        public string YOURSCALARFUNCTION(string PARAMETER)
        {
            List<ObjectParameter> parameters = new List<ObjectParameter>(3);
            parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("PARAMETER", PARAMETER));
            var lObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
            var output = lObjectContext.
                 CreateQuery<string>("YOURMODEL.Store.YOURSCALARFUNCTION(@PARAMETER)", parameters.ToArray())
                .Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            return output;
        }
```

Be sure that you have your function added to YOURMODEL.EDMX, should be some thing like this:

```
<Function Name="YOURSCALARFUNCTION" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" ReturnType="nvarchar(max)">
          <Parameter Name="PARAMETER" Type="nvarchar(max)" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
```