# Entity Framework error 6046: still showing upon model validation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've added my own code to my partial `DbContext` model class. I can invoke the scalar function from my code.

The function is correctly declared in my `.edmx` file. But still, the Entity Framework throws warning 6046 upon validation of my model.

Here is my partial `DbContext` class code:

```
public partial class NrgNetContext : DbContext
{
    public System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext AsObjectContext()
    {
        return (this as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }

    [DbFunction("NrgNetModel.Store", "SfnFinMovCuentasBancariasSaldoInicial")]
    public decimal SfnFinMovCuentasBancariasSaldoInicial(Guid CartCuentaBancariaId, Guid CuentaId, DateTime FechaInicial)
    {
        var paramList = new ObjectParameter[]
        {
            new ObjectParameter("CartCuentaBancariaId", CartCuentaBancariaId),
            new ObjectParameter("CuentaId", CuentaId),
            new ObjectParameter("FechaInicial", FechaInicial)
        };

        return this.AsObjectContext().CreateQuery<decimal>("NrgNetModel.Store.SfnFinMovCuentasBancariasSaldoInicial", paramList).Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24161005/861716

Comment: Dear Gert, I read the reference before writing my new question. As a matter of fact I used the reference in order to implement the solution.

What I'm telling here is: After implementing the referenced solution, when I validate my model, it still throws the warning: error 6046 for the scalar function.

Thanks.